# Displaying img inline inside floated element for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Having a headache with IE. I have an image (24x24) which I'd like to display inline beside my username at the top navigation bar after logging in. It shows nicely in firefox, chrome. problem with IE version 7. The img breaks to another line, and other sibling items in the  float back left.

CSS below:

```
    #nav {
           background:url("../images/nav-bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
           height:35px;
           line-height:35px;
    }
    #nav .menuitem{
        padding: 0 7px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 11px;
        float:left;
    }
    #nav .menuitem, #nav .menuitem a {
        color:#CCCCCC;  
    }
    #nav .menuitem:hover {
        background-color:#333333;
    }
    #nav .menuitem img {
           -moz-border-radius:3px;
           -webkit-border-radius:3px;
           border:1px solid #111;
           float: right;
           margin-top: 4px;
           margin-left: 7px;
           height:24px;
           width:24px;
    }
    #nav .right {
        float:right;
    }
```

I have tried many variations but can't seem to fix the problem. I have also tried variations of the css below, but the image still doesn't show nicely inline.

```
#nav .menuitem img {
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #111;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    height:24px;
    width:24px;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    top: 0px;
    line-height: 35px;
}
```

The HTML code as follows

```
<span class="menuitem right">Welcome, <a id="profile" href="http://localhost/usercp">user<img src="avatar24x24.jpg"></a></span>
```

Comment: Works fine as is in IE7 here. http://jsfiddle.net/p6Mug/

Comment: @Kyle - you have no `#nav` element.

Comment: True, just copied the code from OP's question, but here is an update http://jsfiddle.net/p6Mug/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a background image instead, like this:

```
<a style="background-image: url(avatar24x24.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: right center; padding-right: 30px;"
          id="profile" href="http://localhost/usercp">user</a>
```

Should position it pretty well, tested it in Opera, IE8 compatability mode and Firefox. To display the entire image, tune the height of the elements around it.

You can use background-position to move the image around inside the surrounding element, there's more information on this at [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp).

Alternatively, you can use margin to get more spacing (margin will create spacing that includes the background image).

Comment: i got it to display nicely in IE with your snippet there, but used the style on the parent span .menuitem instead. one minor annoyance though, how do i add padding to the image? it goes all the way right, i'll need some padding for hovering

Comment: You can use background-position to move the image around inside the surrounding element, see: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp Alternatively, you can use margin to get more spacing (margin will create spacing that includes the background image).

Comment: i used a background-position:92% and it's perfect. thanks a lot! also just to share with everyone, margin does not get hovered, only padding does. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I altered the **css and html source**. I only have IE6 to work with, but it looks consistent in Chrome and IE6. Try this:

http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/38/run

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title></title> 
    <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
    * { margin:0; padding:0; }

    #nav {
           background:url("../images/nav-bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
           height:35px;
           line-height:35px;
    }

    #nav .menuitem{
        padding: 0 7px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 11px;
        float:left;
    }
    #nav .menuitem, #nav .menuitem a {
        color:#CCCCCC;  
    }
    #nav .menuitem:hover {
        background-color:#333333;
    }
    #nav .menuitem img {
           -moz-border-radius:3px;
           -webkit-border-radius:3px;
           border:1px solid #111;
           display:inline-block;
           margin-top: 4px;
           margin-left: 7px;
           height:24px;
           width:24px;
    }
#nav a { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; }
.lol { display:inline-block; }
    #nav .right {
        float:right;
    }

    </style> 

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
#nav .menuitem a { display:inline; zoom:1; }
#nav .menuitem img { display:inline; zoom:1; border:1px solid red; vertical-align:top; }
</style>
<![endif]--> 

</head> 
<body> 

<div id="nav"> 

<div class="right menuitem"> 
<span class="lol">Welcome,</span> <a id="profile" href="http://localhost/usercp">user</a> <a id="profile-img" href="http://localhost/usercp"><img src="http://cdn1.sbnation.com/profile_images/273745/battle_scars_fedor_emelianenko_by_wildestdreamz_small.jpg"></a> 
</div> 

</div> 





</body> 
</html>
```

This snippet suffered from the [float:right width calculation bug](http://work.arounds.org/issue/27/floats-containing-float-right-expand-full-width-ie/) and I had to use inline-block workaround to get it to work right.